# Connect to CloudSQL from Spring native app in Cloud Run

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Spring Boot 3 app that I compile to a native image using the spring-boot-maven-plugin. This app is deployed to Google Cloud Run. It is important for this app to be a native image because we scale this to 0 instances and it needs to boot quickly on incoming requests.

Now this app must connect to a Cloud SQL Postgres database. I added Spring Data JPA and built the jdbc url using the `com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory` (using the spring-cloud-gcp-sql library does not work in native mode).

Now, everytime the app is started, RSA keys are generated (`First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.`) which takes about 1 second. This is negligible in a normal Spring Boot app but huge in a native image. This takes the startup time from ~300 milliseconds to around 1.3 seconds.

So I tried to activate the Cloud SQL proxy that is built into Cloud Run. This mounts a unix socket into the container that the JDBC driver can then connect to. Unfortunately, the ffi library (`jnr-unixsocket`) does not work in native image mode either.

My options from here seem to be

1. Build my own socket factory based on the unix socket support in Java >= 16, as described here: https://www.morling.dev/blog/talking-to-postgres-through-java-16-unix-domain-socket-channels/
2. Abandon the "scale to 0" premise and always run an instance. This still leaves the problem of "slow" scaling in load peak scenarios
3. Connect to the database using a private IP (via VPC connector) without the socket factory. This seems to work ok-ish (I can not use service accounts in this case) but our IT requires client certificates in Cloud SQL databases. I could generate static client certificates and use those in the JDBC driver. This is problematic because the certs need to be stored somewhere safely (like Google Secret Manager) and would have to be downloaded before establishing a database connection.

Is there anything I am missing? Is it possible to access the Cloud SQL proxy via IP address? (connecting to 127.0.0.1:5432 did not work)?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Cloud SQL Postgres, you can choose between the two which are using a database client or Cloud SQL Auth proxy. you may check out this documentation regarding with [Connect using Cloud SQL connectors](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors).

Cloud SQL Auth Proxy has 2 methods: [TCP and Unix Socket](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#startup_options).
Cloud SQL Auth proxy will provide you to distinguish whether it will listen to TCP port or Unix socket. Unix Socket creates the location that you implemented. meanwhile, TCP listens on the `localhost` by its default.

Also note that the Cloud SQL Auth proxy does not support Unix sockets on Windows. Linux-based operating systems have a maximum socket path length of 108 characters. If the total length of the path exceeds this length, you cannot connect.

To access Cloud SQL proxy that is built into Cloud Run. Cloud SQL proxy via IP address, You can check this documentation that provides the connection whether you need to [connect via Public or Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview#connection_options).

There are two options to connect your Cloud Run to Cloud SQL:

- Configure private services access for Cloud SQL. you can also
  build a private IP for a new instance or an existing one. Additional information can be found on this title [Configure private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip).
- Configure serverless VPC access also configure it with the proper
  region so that you can access it through your Cloud Run. for more information can be found in this title [Configure Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#creating_a_connector).

Hope this helps.